# Clickhouse: is there any way to drop multi-partition in one `alter table drop partition ****` query?

Tags: clickhouse

In clickhouse, the table is partitioned by day. Now I want to drop multi-partition in one `alter` query for convenience.

I've done this by shell using while loop:

```
while [[ $startDate < $endDate ]]
do
    clickhouse-client --query="alter table db.table drop partition toYYYYMMDD(toDate($startDate))"
    startDate=`date -d "+1 day $startDate" +%Y-%m-%d`
done
```

And I just want to find some way that can do this easily. Is there some way? Thanks~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can instead use `ALTER TABLE <table> DELETE WHERE <partition-filters>` to drop multiple partitions in one go.

Comment: How does `<partition-filters>` look like? I tried `ALTER TABLE <table> DELETE WHERE partition='20181001'` and `ALTER TABLE <table> DELETE WHERE partition like '%201810%'`, but received exception from clickhouse: unkown identifier.

Comment: Suppose your partition column has name `parcol`. You can write something like this `alter table db.table delete where parcol between toYYYYMMDD(toDate($startDate)) and toYYYYMMDD(toDate($endDate))`

Comment: Thanks~. Suppose I have a table column `date` whose type is `Date`, and the table is partitioned by `toYYYYMMDD(date)`. What you really mean is that I can use `delete` like this: `alter table db.table delete where date between '2018-10-01' and '2018-11-01'`. But how about partitioned by month, is this way efficient for dropping.

Comment: `toYYYYMMDD` is monotonic so clickhouse will smartly pick up the correct partition pruning plan, same applies to tables partitioned by month. You can write `where toYYYYMMDD(date) between ... and ...` which resembles the partitioning scheme. I didn't do thorough tests on this topic, so please try it out and see if it's indeed efficient.

Comment: The method you proposed is based on the suppose that the table had a column `parcol`. But for all of our tables doesn't have this column. Anyway it's a good idea for higher version of ck to use `delete`. Thanks~

Comment: Is there any performance difference between using drop and delete where?

Comment: `DROP PARTITION` is more efficient since it doesn't read anything - only deletes. `ALTER DELETE` reads columns to check the condition.

Comment: If the condition is a range of partitions, it would just delete the partition directories, so there would be no difference from using drop statement. Am I right?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ON CLUSTER 'my-cluster'
    DROP PARTITION '2020-01-01',
    DROP PARTITION '2020-01-02',
    DROP PARTITION '2020-01-03'
```

Unfortunately, seems like there is nothing more convenient yet.